# tensorflow internal error that fails to create session

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a simple neural network using tensorflow with gpu on Jupyter Notebook, but it fails every time to create a session, I have traced the code many times and reduced the number of iterations to 10, and also reduced the number of input tain and test data,just for testing if it was a problem of computational power. My network have 2 hidden layers; the first contains 3 neurons and the second contains 2. 
here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import math
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from preprocessing import load_dataset



def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate=0.0001):
"""
Arguments:
X_train -- training set, of shape (input size , number of training examples )
Y_train -- test set, of shape (output size , number of training examples )
X_test -- training set, of shape (input size , number of test examples )
Y_test -- test set, of shape (output size, number of test examples )
learning_rate -- learning rate of the optimization

Returns:
parameters -- parameters learnt by the model.
"""

ops.reset_default_graph()  
X, Y = create_placeholders()
parameters = initialize_parameters()
Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)
print("X = " + str(X))
print("Y = " + str(Y))
print("Z3 = " + str(Z3))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(10):
        print(sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train}))

    parameters = sess.run(parameters)
    print("Parameters have been trained!")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Z3), tf.argmax(Y))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

    print("Train Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train}))
    print("Test Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test}))

    return parameters

X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test=load_dataset()
parameters= model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
```

and here are the functions that I'm calling

```
 def create_placeholders():
    X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(28755648, 5), name="X")
    Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 5), name="Y")

    return X, Y
    def initialize_parameters():
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [3, 28755648], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=0))
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [3, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", [2, 3], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=0))
    b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [2, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", [1, 2], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=0))
    b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", [1, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    parameters = {"W1": W1,
                  "b1": b1,
                  "W2": W2,
                  "b2": b2,
                  "W3": W3,
                  "b3": b3}

    return parameters

def forward_propagation(X, parameters):
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    b1 = parameters['b1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    b2 = parameters['b2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']
    b3 = parameters['b3']


    Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, X), b1)     
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)                   
    Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, A1), b2)    
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)                   
    Z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W3, A2), b3)    

    return Z3

 def compute_cost(Z3, Y):
    logits = Z3
    labels = Y
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))


    return cost
```

And every time I run the code I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-9ce12ddb96d9> in <module>()
----> 1 parameters= model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)

<ipython-input-38-ab5d84d97720> in model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate)
     42 
     43     # Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
---> 44     with tf.Session() as sess:
     45 
     46         # Run the initialization

C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
   1480 
   1481     """
-> 1482     super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
   1483     # NOTE(mrry): Create these on first `__enter__` to avoid a reference cycle.
   1484     self._default_graph_context_manager = None

C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
    620           # pylint: enable=protected-access
    621         else:
--> 622           self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
    623     finally:
    624       tf_session.TF_DeleteSessionOptions(opts)

C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    471             None, None,
    472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    475     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

On the other hand, I have tried to create new session and run a simple tensorflow graph, and it worked well.
If anyone could help in my case I would be pleased

Comment: What is ops in your code? In ```ops.reset_default_graph()```? Why not ```tf.reset_default_graph()```?

Comment: I'm learning deep learningfrom corsera Andrew Ng sprcilization and  course used  ops.reset_default_graph() after importing from tensorflow.python.framework

Comment: That is fine, but where did you define ops? Can you try with tf? Or at least post the entire code so that we can check all parts of it?

Comment: @Umberto I have edited the question and inserted the missing details ande tried tf.reset_default_graph() and gave me the same error

Comment: Ok Thanks. I don't have a working installation of Python and tensorflow where I am now, but I will try your code later in the afternoon. Will let you know what I find out.

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow? And which CUDA version? Sounds like an installation issue rather than something to do with the model; can you reproduce by just opening a Session without doing graph building first?

Comment: @AllenLavoie it's CUDBB version 6.0 for windows 10-x64 and CUDA toolkit 8.0, using anaconda with python 3.6... it worked pretty well when running the session even with a small graph for test, but when it come to that one above it just stops by that error.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Are you close to out of memory? It looks like `new` is returning a null pointer. (If so, this error message should be improved...)

Comment: @AllenLavoie Yeah it seems to, I have decreased the number of input features of my training data, it's now running, thank you... but I do want to understand which method returns a null pointer ?

Comment: My guess is that it's [this new](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4ad12049d0c93155a8137b7d656136885335374b/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L173), called from [NewSession](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4ad12049d0c93155a8137b7d656136885335374b/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/session.cc#L74) through a bit of a maze of SessionFactory calls. Maybe that error message should just have an "(out of memory?)" appended to it.

Answer (score -1):

Put `tf.reset_default_graph()` before creating the `tf.Session()` should solve the problem.